# A good Android and Web Services structure

Tags: android, web-services

Suppose I have to make the following things:

1. An Android app that must send informations periodically to a database (without the interaction of the user)
2. Moreover, this android app, must provide various services to the user (user interaction)
3. Also, i want to provide a web interaction to the user, and for it i would like to use Vaadin
4. I use MySQL for the database

Is it correct to have this structure?

**Android <--> PHP <--> MySQL Database (using XAMPP)**

**Vaadin (web side) <--> JDBC <--> MySQL Database (the same database as above)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not incorrect but you are creating double work. You are creating web services in PHP to service the android client call this API1 then you are creating a Vaadin based web site which also acts as an API call it API2.

Two API's in different frameworks to maintain which is just adding more maintenance and complexity. If the web site mimics the android application you will essentially be duplicating the code.

Or if you want that in pictures:

[image: Duplication Of Effort]

Create a web-services API that will be used by Vaadin and the Android application. This will eliminate the double work. If you create the Web-services using REST or SOAP you will be able to reuse those services across both front end application. Now when you grow the application i.e. you want to add iPhone you can simply consume the same services.

Or in pictures:

[image]

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. May i have some additional information about the implementation of this Web Services Server? Internet is full of tutorials about android and php, but php is not included in this structure.

Comment: You can use PHP, Java, .Net and any other technology to implement SOAP/REST services. Since you are going to use Vaadin which is Java based maybe it is wise to stick to only Java then. The main thing to understand is web-services as a concept. Then look at how to implement them in a technology stack.